Value doesn't change even though select is set to the model
I use select2 to style selects. But in livewire I faced a problem that when I change the value it doesn't change even though the select is set to model
<div class="select2-custom-field select2-without-search">
    <select class="form-control height-40" wire:model="interval">
        @foreach(\App\Models\SavedSearch::listInterval() as $key => $value)
            <option {{$key == \App\Models\SavedSearch::INTERVAL_WEEK ? 'selected' : ''}} value="{{$key}}">{{$value}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

I tried adding onchange="@this.call('changeInterval', $(this).val());", but then the select, after selecting the value, looks like normal.
Can this be fixed?

Have you tried changing how the selected option is defined in the options tag? As the styling shouldn't normally interfere with livewire assignment to component properties.
<option @if($key == \App\Models\SavedSearch::INTERVAL_WEEK ) selected @endif value="{{$key}}"> {{$value}} </option>


I assume you are using Livewire 3
Add a wire:ignore in the outer <div>
<div wire:ignore class="select2-custom-field select2-without-search">
    .....

or alternatively you can wrap that <div> with an outer <div> containing the wire:ignore attribute:
<div wire:ignore>
    <div class="select2-custom-field select2-without-search">
        .....
    </div>
</div>

In this way Livewire will not update the <select> which is already managed by the select2

Then to update the $interval variable you can set it on the frontend side using the $wire object:
@script
<script>

    // using $wire.set the value is sent immediately to the backend like wire:model.live
    $(() => { $(".select2-custom-field select").on("change", (e) => {
        $wire.set("interval", e.target.value);
    })});

    // alternatively the value can be set locally and can be updated when you apply an explicit update (like a submit) 
    // $(() => { $(".select2-custom-field select").on("change", (e) => {
    //     $wire.interval = e.target.value;
    // })});


</script>
@endascript

